# Probability that at least 1 person receives its letter for a distribution of n letter to n people (paired 1 to 1)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm trying to solve an elementary probability problem, but I don't get the right answer and can't find the flaw in my reasoning. The problem and my (wrong) solution goes as follows.

Somebody distributes randomly $n$ letters to $n$ people, where each person has one letter to which it is addressed. What is the probability that at least one person gets its letter?

Let $E$ be the event such that at least one person gets the right letter. The probability space is $\Omega$. I'll denote cardinality as $\#$. The probability of $E$ is

$$\mathbb{P}(E) = \frac{\#E}{\#\Omega} $$

Obviously, $\#\Omega = n!$ .

To find $E$, I divide it into smaller independent events $A_i$, such that $A_i$ is "exactly $i$ people get the right letter". I thus have

$$\mathbb{P}(E) = \mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{i}A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{P}(A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\# A_i}{n!}$$

I find that $\#A_i$ is the number of unordered combinations of $i$ from $n$, that is $\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}$ . Replacing that in the preceding equation gives me
$$\mathbb{P}(E) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i!(n-i)!}$$

The answer is supposed to be $\mathbb{P}(E) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i!}$ . What is the flaw in my reasoning?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your value for $\#A_i$ is not correct.  Test it: if $n=3$ and $i=2$, what is $\#A_i$ and what does your formula give?

Comment: For $\# A_2$ with $n=3$, I want to find the number of ways that 2 people in 3 get the right letter. Numbering the three persons, it could be person 1 and 2, 1 and 3 or 2 and 3, that is 3 possibilities. My formula gives the same answer. But I know there's something I'm not quite getting.

Comment: Ahh darn, I just got it! Thank you ahah!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that at least one person gets his/her letter is $1$ minus the probability that we have a [derangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

There are $n!$ possible distributions of the $n$ letters to the $n$ people.

If $D(n)$ is the number of derangements of a set of $n$ elements, then the probability $P(n)$ that at least one of the $n$ people does not get his/her letter is $$P(n) = 1 - \frac{D(n)}{n!}$$

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements), $$D(n) = n! \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \frac{\left(-1 \right)^{i}}{i!}$$
$$D(n) = \left\lfloor \frac{n!}{e} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor $$

The second formula for $D(n)$ is far cooler, but the first one solves your problem.

$$P(n) = 1 - \frac{n! \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \frac{\left(-1 \right)^{i}}{i!}}{n!}$$

$$P(n) = 1 - \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \frac{\left(-1 \right)^{i}}{i!}$$

We can cancel the $1$s and reindex to get the form you want:

$$P(n) = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\left(-1 \right)^{i+1}}{i!}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll look up what is derangement and that will probably give me some insight. Though I'm still not getting what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here is what I did wrong.

The events $A_{i}$ are not independent. If (n-1) people get the right letter, then it is sure that the last person also gets his letter.